# Convert haskell style type signature to C

Tags: c, haskell, types, type-conversion

I have a set of haskell type signature, similar to below:
(for anyone that knows haskell, this is a monomorphised version of `..` )

```
(t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t2) ->  t1 -> t3
```

And with the implicit parens (Conveniently, this is how my program currently stores the type signatures - as a tree.):

```
(t2 -> t3) -> ((t1 -> t2) -> (t1 -> t3))
```

I am looking for a programmatic way to convert this style of type signature to a C style type signature with function pointers. So far, all I have been able to find is resources concerning one, maybe two levels of function pointers - Obviously, in this case, I need it to support theoretically infinite levels. Any resources or pointers would be helpful.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Encoding the type as a C datastructure would also work.

Comment: C isn't a general functional language. For any significantly complex functional type, this is a pretty meaningless exercise because C doesn't support functions as first class objects. E.g. there is no notion of a closure. It doesn't have generic types, so there is no way to encode the `ti` or type equivalences involving them.  You _could_ encode the Haskel types as a C data structure, but I guess that's not what you're after.

Comment: Re "*There is no notion of a closure*", There's a library for that, IIRC

Comment: @Gene Actually, encoding them as datastructures would also work now that I think about it. I'll edit the question, but if you know how, i'd be quite grateful.

Comment: If you just want to dump the c style signature from haskell signature so, you can abuse the  gcc compiler to dump it for you, like so `t3 (* (*)(t2 (*)(t1)))(t1)` from the compilation error of code such as https://hastebin.com/ovudopopiv.cpp. All you'd have to do is design a pragmatic way to auto-generate the c source code such as that from a given signature.

Comment: @Gene C has function pointers and they are more than enough to encode this type. Implementing a function of this type in C is a different problem because standard C lacks closures, but there are extension libraries that can help with that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Sure. I didn't say it was impossible. I said it was meaningless because there are no functions of generic type in C. You can only define a function having a concrete instance of the type expression. You can see this where Dmitry verified his example. He was forced to pick real types for the type variables in order to create a function.

Comment: @Gene Not really meaningless. If you disallow polymorphic recursion (a dubious feature anyway) then any program can be translated to one with no polymorphic functions at all (but with some code duplication). It could be a viable implementation strategy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If @Dmitry's comment accurately reflects what you're trying to do, the Haskell code to perform such a conversion is surprisingly simple:

```
data HType = (:->) HType HType | H String
  deriving (Show)
infixr 0 :->

ctype :: String -> HType -> String
ctype x (a :-> b) = ctype ("(*" ++ x ++ ")(" ++ ctype "" a ++ ")") b
ctype "" (H a) = a
ctype x  (H a) = a ++ " " ++ x

main = do
  let t = (H "t2" :-> H "t3") :-> (H "t1" :-> H "t2") :-> H "t1" :-> H "t3"
  putStrLn $ ctype "compose" t
```

For this example, it produces the type signature:

```
t3 (*(*(*compose)(t3 (*)(t2)))(t2 (*)(t1)))(t1)
```

which does, indeed, describe a type `compose` that's a pointer to a function that accepts a pointer to a function `t2 -> t3`, returning a pointer to a function that accepts a pointer to a function `t1 -> t2` that returns a pointer to a function `t1 -> t3`.

It's a little hard to see how such a type could be used.  I mean, if you want to emit code for a compose function that could actually be assigned to such a pointer, it's tough to do without first-class functions.  As a proof of concept, here's a non-reentrant version using global variables that proves that the type "works":

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* some concrete types to use */
typedef char t1;
typedef int t2;
typedef char* t3;

/* compose :: (t2 -> t3) -> ((t1 -> t2) -> (t1 -> t3)) */
typedef t3 (*(*(*compose)(t3 (*)(t2)))(t2 (*)(t1)))(t1);

/* code defining a `do_compose` function pointer of C type `compose` */

t3 (*f1)(t2);
t2 (*f2)(t1);

t3 compose2(t1 x)
{
        return (*f1)((*f2)(x));
}

t3 (*compose1(t2 (*g)(t1)))(t1)
{
        f2 = g;
        return compose2;
}

t3 (*(*compose0(t3 (*f)(t2)))(t2 (*)(t1)))(t1)
{
        f1 = f;
        return compose1;
}

compose do_compose = compose0;

/*
 * a test case for `do_compose`
 */

/* ord :: t1 -> t2 */
int ord(char c)
{
        return (int)c;
}

/* print :: t2 -> t3 */
char* print(int i)
{
        static char buffer[256];
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
        return buffer;
}

int main()
{
        puts(do_compose(print)(ord)('A'));
}
```

Alternatively, if you want an "uncurried" version of the type, which in this case would be:

```
t3 (*compose)(t3 (*)(t2), t2 (*)(t1), t1)
```

(i.e., `compose` is a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a function `t2 -> t3`, a pointer to a function `t1 -> t2`, and a value of type `t1` and then returns a value of type `t3`), the Haskell code still isn't too bad:

```
ctype' :: String -> HType -> String
ctype' "" (H a) = a
ctype' x (H a) = a ++ " " ++ x
ctype' x funcall = go [] funcall
  where go args (a :-> b) = go (ctype "" a : args) b
        go args b = ctype ("(*" ++ x ++ ")(" ++ intercalate ", " (reverse args) ++ ")") b
```

The resulting function is much more ergonomic for implementation in C:

```
/* compose :: (t2 -> t3) -> ((t1 -> t2) -> (t1 -> t3)), uncurried version */
typedef t3 (*compose)(t3 (*)(t2), t2 (*)(t1), t1);

t3 compose0(t3 (*f)(t2), t2 (*g)(t1), t1 x)
{
        return (*f)((*g)(x));
}

compose do_compose = compose0;

...

int main()
{
        puts(do_compose(print, ord, 'A'));
}
```

Comment: As a bit of explanation - I'm making a small compiler that transpiles from a haskell-like syntax to C, hence the style conversion between haskell-like to c-like. I have a *lot* of control over function output, and as a result, everything is curried implicitly. Therefor, I don't need to worry about `myfunc(x)(y)(z)`, as I can just emit it as 3 seperate calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a C data structure, this will do it (quick and dirty):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct type_s {
  enum { FUNCTION, VAR } kind;
  union {
    struct function_s {
      struct type_s *from;
      struct type_s *to;
    } function;
    int var_n;
  };
} TYPE;

TYPE *make_function(TYPE *from, TYPE *to) {
  TYPE *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
  t->kind = FUNCTION;
  t->function.from = from;
  t->function.to = to;
  return t;
}

TYPE *make_var(int n) {
  TYPE *t = malloc(sizeof *t);
  t->kind = VAR;
  t->var_n = n;
  return t;
}

void print(TYPE *t) {
  switch (t->kind) {
    case FUNCTION:
      printf("(");
      print(t->function.from);
      printf(" -> ");
      print(t->function.to);
      printf(")");
      break;
    case VAR:
      printf("t%d", t->var_n);
      break;
    default:
      printf("Bad type kind %d\n", t->kind);
      exit(1);
  }
}

typedef enum { LP, RP, ID, ARROW, END_INPUT } TOKEN;
static char *token_str[] = { "(", ")", "ID", "->", "<end>", };

static int scanned_id;
static int ch;

void get_next(void) {
  ch = getchar();
}

void require(int required) {
  if (ch != required) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Required %c, saw %c\n", required, ch);
  }
}

TOKEN scan(void) {
  while (isspace(ch)) get_next();
  switch (ch) {
    case '(':
      get_next();
      return LP;
    case ')':
      get_next();
      return RP;
    case '-':
      get_next();
      require('>');
      get_next();
      return ARROW;
    case 't':
      get_next();
      scanned_id = 0;
      while (isdigit(ch)) {
        scanned_id = scanned_id * 10 + (ch - '0');
        get_next();
      }
      return ID;
    case EOF:
      return END_INPUT;
    default:
      fprintf(stderr, "Bad char: %c (%d)\n", ch, ch);
      exit(1);
  }
}

/*
 * Grammar:
 * S -> expr $
 * expr -> term | term -> expr
 * term -> ID | LP expr RP
 */

TOKEN tok;

void advance(void) {
  tok = scan();
}

void match(TOKEN t) {
  if (tok != t) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Expected %s, found %s\n", token_str[t], token_str[tok]);
    exit(1);
  }
  advance();
}

TYPE *expr(void);
TYPE *term(void);

TYPE *parse(void) {
  TYPE *t = expr();
  match(END_INPUT);
  return t;
}

TYPE *expr(void) {
  TYPE *t = term();
  if (tok == ARROW) {
    advance();
    return make_function(t, expr());
  }
  return t;
}

TYPE *term(void) {
  if (tok == ID) {
    TYPE *t = make_var(scanned_id);
    advance();
    return t;
  }
  match(LP);
  TYPE *t = expr();
  match(RP);
  return t;
}

int main(void) {
  get_next();
  advance();
  TYPE *t = parse();
  print(t);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```